# Meteor.user() undefined when refreshing using angular ui-router and alanning:roles

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, roles

I came into an issue when developing an app using meteor, angular, and the packages ui-router and alanning:roles. Inside a component, I wan't a particular route to be available only for logged in users under certain roles, so I configure a component with the following function:

```
function config($stateProvider) {
    'ngInject';

    $stateProvider.state('customers', {
        url: '/customers',
        template: '<customer-list></customer-list>',
        resolve: {
            currentUser($q) { 
                    const userId = Meteor.userId();
                    if (userId && Roles.userIsInRole(userId, ['admin'])) {
                        console.log('customers.USER_REJECTED');
                        return $q.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED');
                    } else {
                        console.log('customers.USER_ALLOWED');
                        return $q.resolve();
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

It works nicely but when I refresh the page, case in which the user, following the logic I have implemented, is then not allowed to access the route, even if he is actually logged in. If then I manually go to /customers, the user is still not allowed to enter, but if I go to other url where the only requirement is to be logged in, the user is allowed to enter. I have checked that when I refresh the page, Meteor.user() returns undefined, so I suppose that's why the checking for the role is returning false. I've checked several solutions proposed in this community, but I can't make work any of them. Could you please give me a hand?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a timing issue, it takes a moment for the user record to be loaded, and the route fires before it's done.

Have look at this answer, it shows a way that I use to make sure that the user record is fully loaded before the route resolves.

[Meteor - Call function before state loaded using ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774910/meteor-call-function-before-state-loaded-using-ui-router/39781789?noredirect=1#comment66947516_39781789)

Answer (score 0):

Just for future people's perusal, I found another way to do it, this one attached to angular-meteor package:

```
resolve: {
        currentUser($meteor) {
            return $meteor.requireValidUser(function(user) {
                if (Roles.userIsInRole(user, ['admin'])) {
                    console.log('organisations.USER_ALLOWED');
                    return true;
                } else {
                    console.log('organisations.USER_REJECTED');
                    return 'AUTH_REQUIRED';
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I've used this function that requires an user to be available and also an extra function that you can pass in to make extra validations. Important note, in the angular-meteor documentation, they say this is to be deprecated in 1.4, so I still marked the previous solution as the good one.

Best regards,